# Show only one poi on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

<strike>There are more businesses on the same address. I need to implement a map for one which is only visible as a POI when you search for it's name in the google maps.
Can I somehow force to show the one I need, or hide everything and show only that one? I have the placeID for it, and every other information, but I cannot find any solution.</strike>

**Rephrased question:**

There are two businesses in the same building (same address): `BS Agency`, and `XY Agency`. On *maps.google.com* `BS Agency` is only visible as a **POI** when I search the correct name: `BS Agency` or on max zoom level, in other cases only `XY Agency` is shown for that address.

I need to use the Maps JS API to create a map on the BS Agency's website.
If I put the marker with coordinates or I search for the `BS Agency` by placeID using the Places API and put the marker on it's location, I see only the XY Agency on the map.

**Question:** Can I somehow select the `BS Agency` to be visible or hide the `XY Agency`?

Comment: **unclear what you're asking**:
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: A concrete example would be better than BS/XY.

Comment: Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYyajO

Comment: I think this is not related to the API but to how Google handles display of businesses on their maps. Will try to find more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this Q/A:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/map-maker/NfgnDzNHQ-g/d3zK963n2TQJ

And the documentation here:
https://support.google.com/business/answer/6056435?hl=en

> The place labels shown on Google Maps are determined algorithmically based on a large number of factors. One factor these algorithms consider is the accuracy of the business information and the richness of the content associated with the business.
>
> [Verifying your business](https://support.google.com/business/answer/2911778) improves the chances that your business will display with a place label.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your research and answer. In this case the problem is that the two companies are basically the same, and possibly I need to use the maps for both :) I think showing different labels should be available through the placeId, but until they make this (if they will), I will need to find some alternatives. Because there is no possibility through the API and I have enough information, I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I think you'd better merge the two businesses (in terms of place labels) and/or create your map, hide the POIs and put your own marker(s) with the information you need in an infowindow.